# A problem of binding rigify_Controls and mixamo armature

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on

I'm using the Expy-Kit add-on to convert mixamo armature to blender rig then try to bind the walking armature and this happens.
[image]

What happens to my character and how to fix it?

update:
The arms didn't follow the armature.
[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Have you followed some tutorial? Like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ars_rEC3oP8

Comment: I find out the first picture problem is the rotation of the armature. But now there is a second problem pop up...

Comment: i have the same problem too
any solution?